# Any way to join a Hazelcast cluster on fly

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast

Is there any way to let a Hazelcast instance (may client) to join an existing Hazelcast Cluster?

Hazelcast version 5.3.

Comment: What do you mean client joining existing cluster ? This is something that both the client and members of the cluster can do out of the box